# Send seperate column info when specific text is entered in one cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a job tracking spreadsheet, with Column A denoting Job Number and Column "I" denoting job status, which has different stages selectable from a dropdown.

I want an email to be sent to one recipient when the option "Completed" is chosen for the dropdown, also telling them the same jobs number. No matter what I try we can only get it to work for any change to column "I", rather than just "complete". Any help would be appreciated!

```
function sendNotification() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
  var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
  var recipients = "xxx@xxx.co.uk";
  var message = '';
  if(cell.indexOf('I')!=-1){ 
    message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue()
  }
  var subject = 'Job List: '+sheet.getName() 'has been updated' ;
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated.\n\n New Job Status: ' + cellvalue + '.\n\nFor Job Number: ' + message + '\n\nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: ' + row + '.';
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not checking the cell value anywhere.  I've modified your code, and changed the logic so that the code first checks for the column letter "I", and if the column letter "I" was not edited, then halt the code.

Then, if the code gets past that test, the next text is the value of the edited cell.  There is no point in running lines of code that aren't needed to run if it's not column "I" or the correct value.  So I changed the order of a couple lines of code.

```
function sendNotification() {
  var activeCellAddress,cellvalue,message,row,sheet,ss;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  activeCellAddress = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();

  if (activeCellAddress.indexOf('I') === -1){ //If the cell edited is not in column I then quit here
    return;
  }

  cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();

  if (cellvalue !== "complete") {//The the cell value is not the string complete then quit
    return;
  }

  row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();

  var recipients = "xxx@xxx.co.uk";

  message = sheet.getRange('A'+ sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex()).getValue();

  var subject = 'Job List: ' + sheet.getName() + 'has been updated';
  var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated.\n\n New Job Status: ' + cellvalue + '.\n\nFor Job Number: ' + message + '\n\nVisit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: ' + row + '.';

  MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

There was also an error in this line of code:

```
var subject = 'Job List: ' + sheet.getName() + 'has been updated';
```

It was missing an plus sign.